# Jquery Onclick onClickelse

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

Sorry, I have searched for this and cannot seem to get anywhere, tried so many variations:

```
$("#shopipadopen").click(function () {
    $(".newshopipad").height(270);
    return false;
}, {
    $(".newshopipad").height(24);
    return false;
});
```

When the item is clicked, do something, if it clicked again, do something else, I am sure it was that above or this (without using if else)

```
$("#shopipadopen").click(function () {
    $(".newshopipad").height(270);
    return false;
}, function (){
    $(".newshopipad").height(24);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#shopipadopen").live('click', function () {
    var height = $(".newshopipad").height();

    if(height == 270)
        $(".newshopipad").height(24);
    else
        $(".newshopipad").height(270);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, I was just making an if else and was about to ask how to get the .value of height, brilliant and well though, I wish I could up vote.

Answer (score 1):

There is $.one so you can do something like this

```
$("#newshopipad").one("click", function() {
   $(".newshopipad").height(270);
   $("#shopipadopen").click( function(){
       $(".newshopipad").height(24);
       return false;
   } );
   return false;
});
```

Comment: yes, the first time it executes, it will create a click handler for the second and any future clicks; so the first time you click it will set the height to 270, any future clicks will set the height to 24